# Creating table from csv using sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, bulkinsert, create-table

I was creating table name "tripsdata" in SQL query tool, which is done successfully. Now I have to insert values into the table and I used the below syntax :

```
LOAD data INFILE 'tripsdata.csv' 
INTO TABLE tripsdata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

It keeps giving me error - **"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "data"
LINE 2: LOAD data INFILE 'tripsdata.csv' "**

Can you share the error and rectification?

tried what I mentioned above. I want to create this table using SQL query:

Comment: PostgreSQL uses COPY not LOAD

Comment: Here's the link to the manual, with all the different statements. And LOAD is not one one them: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html

Comment: COPY doesn't have a SKIP or `IGNORE N ROWS` option. Is the actual problem how to ignore the header row? In that case you need to use `HEADER ON`. If you want to match header and column names, `HEADER MATCH`

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD DATA` is a MySQL command. PostgresSQL uses [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). I suspect what you're trying to do is import a CSV file while skipping the header row. You can do that with the `FORMAT CSV` and `HEADER ON` options:

```
COPY country 
FROM '/path/to/tripsdata.csv' 
(FORMAT CSV,HEADER ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well try this query:

`COPY tripsdata FROM 'tripsdata.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I tried this and the error pertains - "ERROR:  could not open file "/path/to/tripsdata.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy."